# Panel management in Unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, menu, assets, panels

How do you manage transitions between your panels/menus in Unity? Do you use any kind of assets? I want to have all of the transitions/events/animations be handled and easy to script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iTween](http://www.pixelplacement.com/itween/index.php) for transitions and animations. Is a very nice asset for free with a lot of options and easy to use.
In the website you can check the [documentation](http://www.pixelplacement.com/itween/documentation.php) and some [examples code](http://www.pixelplacement.com/itween/examples.php)

Another great option for a cool UI with a lot of options with scripts ready to use is [NGUI](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2413). Is a complete UI extension